# How to set mouse scrolling speed for all users?

Tags: mouse, windows-registry, group-policy, windows-server-2016

I am searching for a way to increase the mouse scrolling speed on Windows Server 2016 from the default value (3) up to 20 for all users (HKLM). I am searching for this option since several hours without success.

So far, I only found out how I could do that for the currently logged-in user (HKCU):

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Desktop -> WheelScrollLines=20
```

Any advise about how to do the same for all users either via Group Policy Editor or Registry Editor would be highly appreciated.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35233106/adding-entries-to-hkcu-for-all-users

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've answered your own question already:

You've identified the local user hive and you have Group Policy.

So, now you create a GPO to set the desired value for that key for each user in their own registry hive.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Uff, I am not really familiar with GPO. I only want to set this setting for all users on one machine (server). How can I do that with GPO?

Comment: There is a local Group Policy option, or you create a GP on the domain and just apply it to the single server.